# Horizontal divs alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to align the speakers profiles in the speakers section ..normally all the images are in the same size but I dont know why I get every two lines an element in one line .  :  [here is the page](http://ffr.icompetences.com/#speakers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is some of the .speakers-wrap are different heights. You can give a height to the .speakers-wrap class. E.g.

```
.speakers-wrap {
    height: 280px;
}
```

You'll probably want to adjust this for different screen sizes too.